# How to make custom widget with some dynamic child in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am making a demo for learning basis...where I have created a Custom widget with the use of LISTTILE..

I have actually 3 BottomNvigatationBarItem [ alimonies, favmovies and deletedMovies] which all showing list of movies

but I want trailing different in all 3 screens like

all movies with Delete and Fav icon,
Fav movies with only Fav Icon,
and
Deleted Movies with restore and delete icon

here is my custom widget code

```
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {

  final Movie e;
  final VoidCallback taponfav;
  final VoidCallback tapondel;
  //todo delete should be optional
  MyCard({required this.e,required this.taponfav,required this.tapondel});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(e.name.toString()),
        subtitle: Text(e.language),
        trailing: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            IconButton(
                icon: userlist[0].favmovies.contains(e) == true
                    ? Icon(Icons.favorite)
                    : Icon(Icons.favorite_outline),
                onPressed: taponfav),

            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                onPressed: tapondel),
          ],
        ),
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(e.imageurl),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is a single screen code to show how I use my card

```
 body: ListView(
        children: movielist
            .map((e) => MyCard(e: e, taponfav: (){
          if(userlist[0].favmovies.contains(e)==true)
            userlist[0].favmovies.remove(e);
          else
            userlist[0].favmovies.add(e);

          setState(() {
          });
        },tapondel: (){

              showDialog(context: context, builder: (ctx){

                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Are u sure to delete?...'),
                  actions: [TextButton(onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                    userlist[0].deletedmovies.add(e);

                    movielist.remove(e);
                    setState(() {

                    });

                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
                      content: Text(e.name+' Is Deleted'),));

                  },child: Text('Yes'),),
                  TextButton(onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                  }, child: Text('No')),

                  ],
                );
              });
             setState(() {
             });

        },),)
            .toList(),
      ),
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: In my list tile...number of trailing icon button can be different In all screen where this widget is used...so how to make it dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps.

Create a CardButton class like this.

```
class CardButton {
  final IconData icon;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  CardButton({required this.icon, required this.onTap});
}
```

Modify your card widget like this

```
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCard({Key? key, required this.movie, required this.cardButtons})
      : super(key: key);

  final Movie movie;
  final List<CardButton> cardButtons;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(movie.name.toString()),
        subtitle: Text(movie.language),
        trailing: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < cardButtons.length; i++)
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: cardButtons[i].onTap,
                  icon: Icon(cardButtons[i].icon))
          ],
        ),
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(movie.imageurl),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Access it like this on your main Page

```
ListView(
        children: movielist.map((movie) {
          List<CardButton> cardButtons = [
            CardButton(
                icon: Icons.add,
                onTap: () {
                  print('add');
                }),
            CardButton(
                icon: Icons.delete,
                onTap: () {
                  print('del');
                })
          ];
          return MyCard(movie: movie, cardButtons: cardButtons);
        }).toList(),
      )
```

And you can add or remove or change icons based on the condition on the main page.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this Row Widget: [Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVQap.png) and pass Widget instead. Then implement Your Row Widget As you want every time you call Your custom Widget `MyCard`.

Comment: That's okay..removing is a solution but what if I want to keep it...is it not possible by keeping it...I am confuse with function list..how I can know in advance what row children going to come...

Comment: like array of VoidCallBack